# Redirect URL with Parameters using Regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I use the **Wordpress Redirection** plugin and its working great. Most of my pages are translated so I match using URLs using a regex that check the beginning of the URL.

I would now like to check if the ends with and parameters.

This is what I have now

```
^(/de|/fr|/es|/it)?/company/about/$
```

This does not work if I have any parameters but if I remove `$`, `/company/` will also be effected by the redirect and I do not want it.

How can redirect that exact same URL and include any parameters as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/de|/fr|/es|/it)?/company/about/(\?.+)?$ somewhere
```